# Unity2D jumping with convex shapes as possible ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry if the title is confusing. Basically, what I'm trying to do is make sure the player is grounded (so they can jump again), problem is in my game there will be convex shapes that the player could land on.

The current way I'm doing this is with a raycast, but since the single raycast could only come from somewhere like the centre, I made it so the raycast was going along the bottom of the player instead (this removed the problem where the player couldn't jump if more than half of their body was off a platform).

The raycast along the bottom however made it so if I tried to jump while on a shape like a ramp, it would cause me to go incredibly high, which I don't want.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody2D rBody;
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public int Speed;
    private float lastDistance;
    public bool isGrounded = true;
    private LayerMask environment;
    void Start () {
        environment = LayerMask.GetMask("Environment");
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
        // Check if the user is attempting to jump
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            rBody.velocity = new Vector2(-Speed, rBody.velocity.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
            rBody.velocity = new Vector2(Speed, rBody.velocity.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
            RaycastHit2D hit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(rBody.position+new Vector2(0,-1.5f), Vector2.right,1f,environment);
            if (hit2D) {
                if (hit2D.distance < lastDistance) {
                    lastDistance = hit2D.distance;
                }
                else {
                    lastDistance = 100f;
                    rBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try with `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)`?

Unless the game design it to keep jumping as long as you press space, this might be the reason you are jumping extra high.

If the Raycast solution is still wonky, another way of detecting if the player is grounded is using a `Collider` for the floor and a flag that tells you when you're colliding with it (you can set this flag using `OnCollisionEnter/Exit` or `OnTriggerEnter/Exit`)